# Ajax request mapped to root always

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My ajax requests are always mapped to "/" even after specifying the full path like "/ajax/file/upload"

In my controller, I have the following two methods

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public ModelAndView getView() {
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/file/upload", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String readFile(File file) {
}
```

In client side, when I instantiate an ajax request like "ajax/file/upload", the request has been redirected to the method "getView" instead of "readFile".

I think, this happen because the request mapping "/" also matches the pattern "ajax/file/upload" but not sure though. If thats the case, how to differentiate between the two mappings?

Comment: Just make a base path like `RequestMapping(value = "/WebServices/GetView")` and `RequestMapping(value = "/WebServices/ReadFile")` your base path for all webservices would be `/WebServices` then each path starts with that and has some unique path after that point...

Comment: I can't make a base path like you suggested because I am using spring security for login. It automatically land on the root "/" after authentication.  So I prefer to keep the mapping "/" as such. Is there any other way to get this done?

Comment: You could set the defaultSuccessUrl in your spring security to an existing view i.e. index or home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think, this happen because the request mapping "/" also matches the
>   pattern "ajax/file/upload"

Spring will always use the **best match** to decide wich method should handle the request.

There are a few things that might be happening:

- If in client side you are sending a GET request instead of POST request, the the best match is "/" because "/ajax/file/upload" only accepts POST request. You can debug it in you browser network activity to check the details of the request/response
- If you have security implemented, you need to check that your ajax request is sending the proper cookies/authentication tokens

Another thing that might be worth checking, is if you ajax request sends the header "Accept: application/json" or "Accept: */*"